# Optimizing ng-repeat tilemap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating an mapeditor web application like [tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/)

My ng-repeat looks like this:

```
<div class="mapContainer unselectable" ng-class="{hideBordersFromMapContainer:hideBorders}">
    <div ng-repeat="y in mapDisplayerImages" class="tilegroup" ng-style="{'width':(y.length * 32)+1}">
        <div 
            ng-repeat="x in y" 
            class="tile" 
            ng-mouseover="onMouseOver({'y':$parent.$index,'x':$index})"
            ng-mousedown="drawOrSelectTile({'y':$parent.$index,'x':$index},true);onMouseDown({'y':$parent.$index,'x':$index});" 
            ng-mouseup="onMouseUp({'y':$parent.$index,'x':$index});"
            ng-class="{selectedTile: x.active}" 
        >
            <div
                ng-repeat="image in x.bi" {# ng-repeat bottom images #}
                class="tileImage"
                ng-style="{'background':image}"
            >
            </div>
            <div
                ng-repeat="image in x.ti" {# ng-repeat top images #}
                class="tileImage"
                ng-style="{'background':image}"
            >
            </div>
            <div
            class="tileImage"
            >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It happens to be verry slow rendering and editing when using maps bigger than [50 by 50 tiles](http://prntscr.com/5px8v3).

This means you will have 50 x 50 = 2500 * 2(layers) = 5,000 tiles/divs. And more if there are more bottom images or top images stacked.

Things I tried:

- Replacing {{bind}} with ng-* attributes
- Using current scope variables x or y variable instead of the $scope variable mapDisplayerImages[y] and [y][x]

Are there more things I can do to optimize the mapeditor?

Comment: The issue is you're creating a ton of divs, you might want to look into doing this with a canvas instead.

Comment: Communicating with canvas and angularjs will cost me tons of development time. I will have to set a ton of watchers to redraw the canvas.

Comment: That just might be what you have to do then, if you're setting a ton of watchers there's probably a better method.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to thing about integrating ReactJS in your project.

http://www.williambrownstreet.net/blog/2014/04/faster-angularjs-rendering-angularjs-and-reactjs/